how to separate names into 2 parts?
I have a name list:
data nurse_0;
input nms $28. ;
 cards;
Abcd Efgxxeg, BSN, RN
Dudng Nioll, RN, CCM
Doujh Keeloou, RN
Hardlop Aceed RN BSN
Jnmjkl Tuutt, BSN  RN, CCM
Kommmbbey Maxxt, RN, CM
;
run;

and I want split the first name and rest of the names w/o any change into 2
colums, first_nm and last_nm:
 first_nm  last_nm
 Abcd      Efgxxeg, BSN, RN
 Dudng     Nioll, RN, CCM
 Doujh     Keeloou, RN
 Hardlop   Aceed RN BSN
 Jnmjkl    Tuutt, BSN  RN, CCM
 Kommmbbey Maxxt, RN, CM


You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

What about middle names, hyphenated names? Two word first names Julie Ann....

data want;
   set nurse_0;
   first_nm = scan(nms, 1);
   last_nm = substr(nms, find(nms, ' ') + 1);
   drop nms;
run;

Result:
first_nm   last_nm
Abcd       Efgxxeg, BSN, RN
Dudng      Nioll, RN, CCM
Doujh      Keeloou, RN
Hardlop    Aceed RN BSN
Jnmjkl     Tuutt, BSN  RN, CCM
Kommmbbey  Maxxt, RN, CM

